# How can I check if any of the values of the object properties are equal to 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

How can I check if any of the values of an object's properties are equal to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to *iterate* over the object keys, and *check the value* of each one:

```
for(var p in x) {
    if(x[p] === 0) {
        console.log("Found!");
    }
}
```

Depending on whether you care about properties that may have been inherited from the `prototype`, you could add a `hasOwnProperty` check in there:

```
for(var p in x) {
    if(x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        if(x[p] === 0) {
            //Found it!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I program in ActionScript, which is a similar dialect, so I am almost sure it will be the same. Please try:

```
if(arr[0] != null)
```

Note that there is a difference between `arr[0]` and `arr["0"]`